# Can I pass a TABLELIKE parameter to a PostgreSQL FUNCTION/PROCEDURE?

Tags: postgresql, functions, user-defined-type

I have a function which returns:

```
TABLE (id TEXT, collected TIMESTAMPTZ)
```

In another function, I would like to be able to pass the result of that first function as a parameter. For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(devices TABLE(id TEXT, collected TIMESTAMPTZ)) ....
```

That syntax gives me an error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "TABLE"
```

Is there some way to accomplish this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008966/postgresql-jdbc-table-valued-parameters

Comment: Ugly, and is problematic for my use case, but thanks for the link!

Comment: PostgreSQL does not support table-valued parameters. You must pass a refcursor.

Comment: Typically, there is a clean solution around the corner if you rethink your approach. Don't pass the resulting table to another function (which is not possible as such in Postgres - [various alternatives exist](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17873935/939860)), but use the table function in the `FROM` list of another query. The question would need to be more specific for a more specific answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda what I am doing, but I want to chain multiple funtuons deep to reuse functions. Ex: `select * from fun1(fun2(param)) ;`

Answer (score 4):

OK, based on feedback from [Erwin Brandstetter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3684/erwin-brandstetter) above, I came up with a VERY nice solution detailed below:

```
CREATE TABLE device_data (
  collected TIMESTAMPTZ,
  id VARCHAR(100),
  data JSON,
  PRIMARY KEY(id,collected)
);

COPY device_data (collected, id, data) FROM stdin;
2016-01-02 00:02:12+00  switch1.mycompany.com   {}
2016-01-02 00:02:12+00  switch2.mycompany.com   {}
2016-01-02 00:02:12+00  switch3.mycompany.com   {}
2016-01-02 00:02:12+00  switch4.mycompany.com   {}
2016-01-02 00:02:12+00  switch5.mycompany.com   {}
2016-01-02 00:02:12+00  switch6.mycompany.com   {}
2016-01-03 00:02:12+00  switch1.mycompany.com   {}
2016-01-03 00:02:12+00  switch3.mycompany.com   {}
2016-01-03 00:02:12+00  switch4.mycompany.com   {}
2016-01-03 00:02:12+00  switch5.mycompany.com   {}
2016-01-03 00:02:12+00  switch6.mycompany.com   {}
\.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_most_recent()
RETURNS TABLE(id TEXT, collected TIMESTAMPTZ) AS $$
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(collected) AS collected
FROM device_data GROUP BY id
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data()
RETURNS TABLE(id TEXT, data JSON) AS $$
SELECT
  d.id,
  d.data
FROM device_data d
INNER JOIN get_most_recent() r ON r.id=d.id AND r.collected=d.collected
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM get_data();
```

Comment: A single query using `distinct on ()` will be more efficient. `select distinct on (id) id, data from device_data order by id, collected desc`: http://rextester.com/WBYA88889